# How to run an SQL query right after Hibernate SessionFactory creates a new connection?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0, utf8mb4

My server uses Hibernate in order to connect to a MySQL db. I'm also using c3p0 for connection pooling. I want to execute a specific sql query once on each connection when it is created, but since I'm using `ComboPooledDataSource`, there is no way to detect when a new session is created.
I found out that I can run my query by enabling test connection on checkout and set the query that I want to run as preferred test query (but it can run more than once).

```
String query = "my query";
comboPooledDataSource.setTestConnectionOnCheckout(true);
comboPooledDataSource.setPreferredTestQuery(query);
```

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

*** Edit ***

I'm trying to make my db accept utf8mb4 characters.
The acceptable way to do it is by applying the following to the my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The problem is that I don't have access to anything but my db, so my solution is to execute `SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;` for each connection.

Comment: whats ur application server? you can configure this in application server configuration while defining the data source - connection url etc

Comment: @Kiran I don't have access to the server configuration. I can only run queries on my db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See c3p0's [ConnectionCustomizer](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#connection_customizers) interface. Override the `onAcquire(...)` method of [AbstractConnectionCustomizer](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/AbstractConnectionCustomizer.html). `onAcquire(...)` is called just once for each Connection, after it has been acquired from the database, before it is made available for check-out by clients.

Or, if you want you can just use c3p0's built-in example for just this sort of use case, [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.example.InitSqlConnectionCustomizer](https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/blob/master/src/java/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/example/InitSqlConnectionCustomizer.java)

In c3p0.properties:

```
c3p0.connectionCustomizerClassName=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.example.InitSqlConnectionCustomizer
c3p0.extensions.initSql=SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```